# Converting integers to list

Tags: list-manipulation, education

I'm trying to get a list output, but I get integer results.

Is there a way to convert integers to a list?

Here is my code:

```
list = {12, 37, 44, 96};
list2 = IntegerDigits[list];
Do[
 list3 = Total[list2[[i]]];
 Print[list3];
 , {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Total /@ IntegerDigits[list]
```

> {3, 10, 8, 15}

Also

```
Total[IntegerDigits[list], {2}] (* thanks: HenrikSchumacher *)
Total[Transpose@IntegerDigits[list]]
FromDigits[#, 1] & /@ IntegerDigits[list]
```

> {3, 10, 8, 15}

Comment: Or `Total[IntegerDigits[list], {2}]`...

Comment: Thank you @HenrikSchumacher; i knew i was missing the most elegant form.

Comment: `Tr /@ IntegerDigits[list]` is actually a bit more efficient. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It does not improve on the previous solutions, but for such manipulations Table is normally enough. For the above lists,

```
Table[Total[list2[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```